# Noun だという adjective+ noun

Tags: particle-と, sentence

私の恋人のみどり
My lover Midori

外面がいいことが悩みだという不器用な人

On the outside is fine she's a clumsy person.

What I don't understand is 悩みだという acting here. Am I missing something?

Comment: Related: [Order of multiple nouns and adjectives modifying the same noun](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/42407/order-of-multiple-nouns-and-adjectives-modifying-the-same-noun)

Answer (score 2):

You can parse it like this:

> 『[外面]{そとづら}がいいことが悩みだ』という［不器用な］人

> *Literally* A ［clumsy］ person who claims "My trouble is that I'm double-faced"

[外面]{そとづら}がいい means "being nice to everybody except one's family".

Answer (score 0):

The clause 悩みだという modifies 不器用. It tells you what kind of clumsy she is: the kind about which one might say (the という construction) "that's distressing/problematic" (悩みだ).

Comment: I think that 悩みだという is modifying 人, or if you will, it is modifying「不器用な人」 as a whole, but it isn't modifying 不器用.